# Centralizar em elemento :after

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o código abaixo:

```
.divCheckList .valorBool, 
.divCheckList .divCheckBox {
    height: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
    border:#CCC .1px solid;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.divCheckList .valorBool {
    line-height: 34px;
}
.divCheckList .divCheckBox .checkBox {
    display: none;
}

.divCheckList .labelCheckBox {
    display:block;
    width:60px;
    height:34px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border:none;
    border-radius:34px;
}

.divCheckList .labelCheckBox:after {
    display:block;
    width:26px;
    height:26px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:#000 .1px solid;
    border-radius:50%;
    content:"";
}
```

html

```
  <div class="divCheckList">
    <label class="valorBool">NÃO</label>
    <div class="divCheckBox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb" class="checkBox">
      <label for="cb" class="labelCheckBox"></label>
    </div>
    <label class="valorBool">SIM</label>
  </div>
```

Que mostra a seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, gostaria de centralizar a bolinha branca de forma tal que ela ficasse espaçada nos cantos e em cima.

Tentei com `margin: 4px;`mas a imagem distorce.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como corrigir?

Comment: Consegui corrigir colocando position: relative na div mais externa e position absolute na label com after. Será que é a maneira correta?

Comment: Esse botão irá mudar de posição ao clicar em "SIM"? Tem que ver como vai ficar com isso.

Comment: Do jeito que está, adicionando `top: 10%; left: 5%; position: relative;` no `:after` ficou ótimo.

Comment: Vou continuar o código com margin:4px; mesmo. Depois vejo se vai dar problema quando for colocar o botão clicavel

Comment: Boto fé........

Comment: outras 2 coisas que eu não consegui entender é porque tanto after quanto before, o elemento criado fica sempre do lado esquerdo do objeto criador e porque a bolinha branca só aparece se acrescentarmos content: ""?

Comment: O lado esquerdo é padrão se vc não posicionar arbitrariamente o elemento. O "content" é o conteúdo do elemento, que pode ser vazio ou não. Se vc não colocar "content", o CSS "entende" que o elemento não existe e não faz nada.

Comment: quer dizer alinhar o elemento nà direita por exemplo? Nesse caso a bolinha vai para direita?

Comment: Pra alinhar a bolinha à direita tem várias formas.

Comment: entendi. Obrigado. Só não entendi por que before e after se qualquer texto colocado na div ao lado do elemento criado por exemplo como after, não "empurra" a bolinha para a direita. o texto fica como fundo.

Comment: É pq a bolinha tem tamanho fixo de 26px.

Comment: e isso faz o texto ficar com fundo na div? Não deveria empurrar a bolinha?

Comment: Não fica no fundo. Fica dentro da div. Não empurra a bolinha pq o tamanho é fixo. Quando vc especifica um tamanho pra div, ela não muda mesmo que vc encha de texto dentro dela.

Comment: Não foi isso que eu quis dizer não. Veja só: temos a div, certo? então dentro dela eu coloco o objeto before, um texto e um objeto after. Ok? Então, O que está acontecendo é que o texto está aparecendo no fundo da div e o objeto before ou o after parece que soibresai ao texto. Faz o seguinte, pega o código que está postado e coloca um texto de uns 50 carcters por exemplo  <label for="cb" class="labelCheckBox">aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</label> e ve o que ocorre.

Comment: Mas não tem before lá.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode, como disse nos comentários, adicionar o `position: relative` na `.labelCheckBox` e `position: absolute` no `:after`.

```
.divCheckList .labelCheckBox {
  position: relative;
  ...
}
.divCheckList .labelCheckBox:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  ...
}
```

E, quando selecionada a opção, aplicar a mudança de posição.

```
.divCheckList .checkBox:checked + .labelCheckBox:after {
  right: 3px;
  left: initial;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umeL5nud/)**

Comment: Seu código ficou excelente, apenas eu botaria `top=12%` pq fica bem no centro. Com `top=3px` fica descentralizado.

Comment: Pra ficar bem no centro mesmo, de forma automática: `top: 50%; -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%); -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%); transform: translate(0, -50%);`.

Comment: Mas o valor certo mesmo seria `top=4px`. (34-26)/2 = 4.

Comment: também foi possível apenas fazendo .divCheckList .divCheckBox .checkBox:checked + .labelCheckBox:before {
 right:0;}, Sem os translate e mantendo margin: 4px; Porém, dessa forma, não dá para fazer a transição até right:0 sem o efeito lento na transição.

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha nesse exemplo da W3Schools
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Comment: Minha linha de partida foi exatamente esse exemplo. Mas queria fazer passo-a-passo para entender o que realmente faz cada linha. Mas, no decorrer do aprendizado, percebi que dava para excluir algumas linhas.